# How to set auto_increment on tinyint in knex.js?

Tags: typescript, sqlite, auto-increment, knex.js

I want to set primary key to tinyint. So I used specificType() method on knex.js.
But error raised.

`table.specificType('id', 'tinyint(1) PRIMARY KEY)'` is worked well.
But I need to set auto increment.
How to set this?

```
migration file "20220609065447_create_roles_table.ts" failed
migration failed with error: create table `roles` (`id` tinyint(1) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(30) not null, `permission` varchar(50) not null, `created_at` datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
create table `roles` (`id` tinyint(1) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(30) not null, `permission` varchar(50) not null, `created_at` datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
Error: create table `roles` (`id` tinyint(1) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(30) not null, `permission` varchar(50) not null, `created_at` datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
```

```js
import { Knex } from 'knex';

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  await knex.schema.createTable('roles', (table) => {
    table.specificType('id', 'tinyint(1) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT');
    table.string('name', 30).notNullable();
    table.string('permission', 50).notNullable();
    table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  });
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  await knex.schema.dropTable('roles');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite there is no `tinyint` data type, although it is allowed to be used in the column's definition.

The only way to make a column autoincremented is to define it as:

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

or:

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Note the data type should be `INTEGER` (any other type, even `INT` will not work) and the correct keyword is `AUTOINCREMENT` and **not** `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Also, there are no `VARCHAR` and `DATETIME` data types in SQLite.
Instead you should use `TEXT`.

Change your table's definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL, 
  `permission` TEXT NOT NULL, 
  `created_at` TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `updated_at` TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

See a [simplified demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ec82879edef887875776f8b54eb60e3e).

You can find more info here: [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: there is no datetime? but I created table with datetime and I checked column type is datetime

Comment: @simonShim SQLite accepts anything as a data type, even nothing. But there is no DATETIME data type. Check the link in my answer.

Comment: can't I use tinyint with autoincrement even on mysql?? I mean I wanna know the way to create column with tinyint that auto increase.

Comment: @simonShim Mysql is not the same as SQLite. Check its documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html